# Why is state not updating in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, state, vuex

I'm using vuex with axios to fetch data from the backend. It shows the updated state when I console-log the state. However, there is always no data when I call the state. Is there something I've missed?

**vuex file**

```
import axios from "axios"; 
import { uid } from "quasar";

const state = {
  data: {},
};

const mutations = { 
  addData(state, payload) {
    state.data[payload.id] = payload.data;
    console.log(state.data); //the data exist
  },
};



 const actions = {
      readData({ commit }) {
        axios({
          method: "get",
          url:
            "https://dev.activate.vi9e.com/api/purchase/receivegoods/index?action=list",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length - 1; i++) {
              let dataId = uid();
              let payload = {
                id: dataId,
                data: response.data[i],
              };
              commit("addData", payload);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            //handle error
            console.log("error message: ", error.message);
          });
      },
    };

const getters = {
  data: (state) => {
    return state.data;
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
};
```

Here is my template:

```
<template>
  <p>{{ data }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("incominggoods", ["readData"]),
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("incominggoods", ["data"]),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readData();
  }

};
</script>
```

Even though, I get the data whenever I console-log in mutations, the data in state is not updating at all. How can I fix this?

**SOLUTION**
Thanks for all the comments. They are all worth problem-solving. The problem is due to the vue's reactivity. Vue seemingly doesn't allow handling the "object" (non-primitive data type) and not allowing the object is assigned by the array assignment way to handle the "Object". This is what I did based on the comments:

1. I manipulated the data that I received from the backend manually (in which it has the "object data type" (non-primitive data type) and changed it to "Object data type").

**In actions (within then(response))**

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          let dataId = uid();

         // manipulate the "object" to "Object"
          let data = {
            poid: response.data[i].purchase_order_id,
            podate: response.data[i].po_date,
            vendor: response.data[i].vendor_name,
            qty: "0%",
            total_qty_ordered: response.data[i].total_qty_ordered,
            total_qty_receivable: response.data[i].total_qty_receivable,
            total_qty_received: response.data[i].total_qty_received,
            status: response.data[i].status,
            barcode: response.data[i].purchase_order_id,
            printed_id: response.data[i].printed_id,
          };
// END OF THE MANIPULATION 

          let payload = {
            id: dataId,
            data: data,
          };
          commit("addData", payload);
```

**In mutations**

```
addData(state, payload) {
    Vue.set(state.data, payload.id, payload.data);
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS reactivity is a bit weird with non-primitive types (objects and arrays, object in further reading).
Imagine an object as a bus with tinted windows. If a passenger (item in an array or key/value in an object) or passengers go in or out of the bus and you were looking at it from the street, you'd have no idea that something changed, the bus still looks the same. That's basically how it works, and you have 2 options for object reactivity.

You can either:

a) replace the whole object

b) in the case of Vue, use Vue.set (for actual objects, not for arrays)

Option a) looks like this:

```
// for objects
const addObjectProperty = (state, property) => {
  state.object = {...state.object, property)
}
// for arrays
const addArrayItem = (state, item) => {
  state.array = [...state.array, item]
}
```

What this is doing, is creating a new object on the fly using object literal syntax (the { } or [ ]). So this way, Vue is looking at your state.object, and see it's replaced with a whole new one and reacts accordingly.

Option b) looks like this:

```
const addObjectProperty = (state, property) => {
  // Vue.set params: object, key, value 
  Vue.set(state.object, state.object[property], property)
}
```

As for arrays, just use array methods, and don't manually change values like `arr[x] = 10` as that will cause the same issue.

EDIT:
If you have a nested object as a state property, you still have to replace the top-level object.

```
state: {
  this: {},
  is: {},
  what: {},
  you: {},
  need: {},
  to: {},
  change: {},
  not: {
    this: {}
  }
}
}
```

The easiest way to go about this if you have lots of nested state is by using [vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also aware of the non-primitive data types that I got from the API and it made me thinking that it might be the problem. What I did was manipulating the data that I got from the backend by defining all of the key/value pairs once at a time. Then, in mutations I use one of the options you provide. I prefer the second option though as it doesn't need another state.object to create. The first option also works for me. Thanks for the concept and the techniques to cope with the problem.

Comment: I'm still figuring out how to convert "object" (non-primitive data type) to "Object" (primitive data type) automatically though? Any idea?

Comment: @auliaamirullah what do you mean? there's no such thing as a primitive type object.

Answer (score 0):

Vue's reactivity system cannot detect object property addition, see [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

In your mutation, change this

```
state.data[payload.id] = payload.data;
```

to this:

```
Vue.set(state.data, payload.id, payload.data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It works for me. The problems were not only about changing the static assignment to vue.set but also the non-primitive data type that I received from the backend hindered the reactivity too. I manipulated the object property manually by defining the key/value pairs one by one and populated them with the data that received. I'm still figuring out how to change the "object" (non-primitive data type) to "Object" (primitive data type) automatically, even though what I've done based on your solution also works well.